# How to query with `sqlite-simple` without having to specify a concrete return type?

Tags: sqlite, haskell, sqlite-simple

Anyone knows if http://hackage.haskell.org/package/sqlite-simple-0.4.9.0/docs/Database-SQLite-Simple.html can run a `query` or `query_` where the rows can be printed without explicitly specifying a return type tuple, for debugging purposes?

Or if not with this package, maybe with another?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I've found a crude way, by going one level deeper, using `direct-sqlite`, the package that `sqlite-simple` builds on top of.

```
import           Database.SQLite.Simple
import           Database.SQLite3.Direct (exec, execWithCallback)

let sql = "SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 3"
let cb count names vals = print vals
execWithCallback (connectionHandle conn) sql cb
```

Which in my case prints something like:

```
[Just "1",Just "2016-01-23 11:25:39.16759",Just "val1"]
[Just "2",Just "2016-01-23 11:25:40.266674",Just "val2"]
[Just "3",Just "2016-01-23 11:25:41.396901",Just "val3"]
```

If anyone else knows of a better way, please do share!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for not scanning for questions related to my library earlier.

Here is one way to print out the raw SQLite values coming out of a SELECT query.  It's not super clean or obvious.

The idea is to define a debug type `DebugShowType` and a `FromField` instance for it that will convert every SQLite row/column into a string.

```
newtype DebugShowType = DebugShowType String deriving (Eq, Show, Typeable)

instance FromField DebugShowType where
  fromField f = cvt f . fieldData $ f where
    cvt _ v = Ok $ DebugShowType (show v)

testShowRawValues :: IO ()
testShowRawValues = do
  elems <- query_ conn "SELECT 13, 'foo'" :: IO [[DebugShowType]]
  mapM_ (\v -> putStrLn (show v ++ "\n"))  elems
```

This should print something like:

```
[DebugShowType "SQLInteger 13",DebugShowType "SQLText \"foo\""]
```

The `Database.SQLite.Simple.setTrace` can also be useful for tracing what values get substituted into your SQL queries.